# How to change text without disrupting the background?

Tags: text, images

How can I change 32 to 37 on this image with the same font size and style preserving the background?

Looking forward to your response. Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Hey mehnaj11, welcome to GD.SE! Please don't use all caps in your title posts, it can come across as yelling. I edited it for you. :) Also, can you tell us a little about what you've tried so far to accomplish what you are trying to do? Explaining what you've tried will improve your question and help you get responses.

Comment: Hi Vicki, thank you. I'm sorry it won't happen again. Appreciate your help. I've done content-aware, clone-stamp, and rasterize but couldn't do it properly. I think somebody edited it for me. Yeheeey!

Answer (score 0):

first you have to find correct font and font-size
for doing this in photoshop, type 37 and set opacity to 50%. after that move text above on 32 and change font and font-size to find the best result!

step2: hide 37's layer and going to use some selection tools like as **marquee tool** and select around 32 (small selection)
after that press **Shift+F5** and in the list select **content-aware** and press OK!
USE IT SEVERAL TIMES TO GET BEST RESULT!

Comment: @mehnaj11 anytime!

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using Adobe **Photoshop**. Photoshop has a **content-aware** tool(am using CC, but other version just below it also have it) that replaces the content of a selection based on the surrounding. Surround the 2 with a neat selection(*Hint: You can use pen tool to draw a path around it and later load it as a selection*). Right click on the selection and choose **Fill>content aware** fill from the pop box. The 2 will be replaced but traces of the edit will remain. Then use the **clone-stamp** tool to clean up the area. (Select desired background and clone it over the traces).

Then type a 7 where the 2 was. (It's good practice to use guides to align the height of the 3 for consistence(One on top, the other at the bottom). 
I have no idea about what font style you used, but 7 is not a tricky figure, most light sans-serif fonts will replace it. Re sizing and scaling it vertically will do the trick.

Add a **drop shadow** on 7, and play around with the spread, angel, blend and size of the shadow. You will have something like this.[image]

The Quality of the edit will depend on the clone-stamping and blending the 7.

Hope this can give you a good start

Comment: iamcastelli - Thank you so much! All the info you have provided is helpful and you even did the modification yourself. You are appreciated.